# How to fix tests after Django 1.10 to 1.11 update

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.11

I'm working on a project that uses Django 1.10 and DRF 3.6.4. When I upgrade Django to 1.11, many tests in classes that inherit from DRF's `APITestCase` fail with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseBadRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

In Django 1.10, however, if I try to access an non-existing attribute of the response, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'ariel'
```

DRF's test client [extends Django's test client](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient), so I suppose that class changed its interface from 1.10 to 1.11 and is doing some magic and returning an instance of this new `HttpResponseBadRequest` class, which doesn't have a "data" attribute. However, I didn't find these changes documented anywhere and I didn't find any discussion online proposing a solution for this. Does anybody have any idea what has to be changed and where I can find documentation for the new test client interface?

## MCVE

### views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status

class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'error': 'My error message'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^path/to/view/$', views.MyView.as_view(), name="my_url")
]
```

### test_views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class TestMyView(APITestCase):
    def test_my_view(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('my_url'),
            data={'some': 'data'},
            format='json',
            HTTP_HOST='host.com'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['error'], "My error message")
        # The line above passes in Django 1.10 and fails in 1.11
```

### Traceback

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_my_view (myapp.tests.test_views.TestMyView)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/webapp/myapp/tests/test_views.py", line 14, in test_my_view
    response.data['error'],
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseBadRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And post the full error traceback.

Comment: The fact you're getting a `HttpResponseBadRequest` object back is more likely something happening in the views than something resulting from the `APITestCase`.  In your tests, before accessing `response.data` you need to check the response is indeed a status 200 response. `HttpResponseBadRequest` is a Django class for status 400 responses. But yeah, we'd need to see a full example to understand why Django is returning a 400 error.

Comment: @KlausD. I've added the MCVE and full traceback

Comment: You might want to use `.json()` instead of `.data`.

Comment: @dirkgroten you're right, the change was probably in how Django creates a response. As should be clear from the example now, it is not unexpected that I'm getting a 400, this is the status code that the test expects. The problem is it cannot read the body of the response anymore because the "data" attribute is not in the response object anymore in Django 1.11.

Comment: @KlausD. I've tried that, but then I got `ValueError: Content-Type header is "text/html", not "application/json"`

Comment: Then you should make sure your API returns JSON with the right content header.

Comment: Something's not right in your views, since you're calling an API view, you actually do want to return a JSON response, i.e. a `Response` object (from DRF) with status 400. You need to check where the response is generated.

Comment: Apparently my `post` method is not even called at all. I don't understand how this is possible. The `as_view` is called and then somehow nothing specified in the view is taken into account anymore and a `HttpResponseBadRequest` response is returned from god knows where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the culprit. From the [Django 1.11 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#miscellaneous):

> **ALLOWED_HOSTS** validation is no longer disabled when running tests. If
>   your application includes tests with custom host names, you must
>   include those host names in ALLOWED_HOSTS. See Tests and multiple host
>   names.

I didn't have 'host.com' in my `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. I have no idea why this was explicitly sent during tests since the setting wasn't even checked anyway. But this is a legacy project with a lot of dubious code so I can't say I am really surprised.

I also had to change all occurrences of `response.data` in the project with `response.json()`.